# IIS Query string lost when using URL Rewrite rules

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to get a site to work with a different URL, basically one is the real URL(fakesite.com) and the other is a Branded URL(NewFakeSite.com). So far ive managed to get it to work so that:

http://fakesite.com/uv/ExpressBranding/ExpressHome.aspx
and
http://NewFakeSite.com/uv/ExpressBranding/ExpressHome.aspx

Both go to the same site and are both able to work as functioning sites. The Problem comes with Querystrings, I cant seem to get the second site to pass along the Querystring so if I go to a URL with a Querystring like:

http://fakesite.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/GeneralInformation.aspx?DashboardId=0

For the Second site it cant find the page and instead gives me:

https://NewFakeSite.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/GeneralInformation.aspx

with no QueryString at all.As such I need to add the Querystring. My webconfig is below, its not just my code so certain pieces of it like the HTTP to HTTPS and adding uv were not written by me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="Redirect to HTTPS" />
                <remove name="Redirect to add uv folder to dotcom" />
                <rule name="Redirect to add uv folder to dotcom" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{map add uv after dotcom:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                        <add input="{SERVER_NAME}" pattern="opterra\.esightenergy\.com" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <serverVariables />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="AddQueryStringForENVIDashBoards">
                    <match url="https://prod.utilityvision.com/uv/EnviSetup/EnviDashboardList.aspx(\?(.*))" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="HTTPS://opterra.esightenergy.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="https://prod.utilityvision.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" exactDestination="false" childOnly="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated I am new to IIS so I hope this is even possible. Thanks!

EDIT: I have tried setting the appendQueryString="True" but still no Querystring. Thanks mjw.

Edit 2: The main goal is to make make it so the URL shows up as something different then it was originally programmed as, The problem is the Query String doesnt come with the rest of the new URL. I have added some code changes to see if this would fix the problem but it did not the URL remained the same. The code sample above is not the original I added this:

```
        <rule name="AddQueryStringForENVIDashBoards">
            <match url="https://prod.utilityvision.com/uv/EnviSetup/EnviDashboardList.aspx(\?(.*))" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="HTTPS://opterra.esightenergy.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{URL}" pattern="https://prod.utilityvision.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/(.*)" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
```

Comment: Looks like you have appendQueryString="false" - make those true.

Comment: hey mjw, I should have mentioned earlier that I tried that. But it did not actually change the URL, The Querystring is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have server variable for query string so you can use it to append value to the redirection url:

> QUERY_STRING

So for your request `http://fakesite.com/uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/GeneralInformation.aspx?DashboardId=0`

Important Server variable values are:

```
HTTP_HOST: www.fakesite.com
PATH: /uv/EnviSetup/Wizard/GeneralInformation.aspx
QUERY_STRING: DashboardId=0
```

Also if you open IIS->Url Rewrite and go to your rule you will see there is a option to test rule, you can simply paste your url and have an overview how URL is parsed. You will then also realize which part you can use to append query string.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

Comment: Hey Thanks for the information i got further but Im still missing something. My code has this now added to it:                   <rule name="AddQueryStringForENVIDashBoards">
                    <match url="\?(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{HTTP_HOST}?{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="\?(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>

Comment: Ok, try to update your question. Copying code inside comment doesn't make sense. It's hard to read. If I understood correctly, you want always to be redirected to fakesite.com? Can you please provide more info in your question so that we can get context what needs to be achieved. Your IIS structure would also help as well as the description of you goal.